# Order data by non-database field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework, Here is my serializers.py for social app:

```
class SocialPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # define field

    class Meta:
        model = SocialPost

    def get_likes(self, obj):
        post_id = obj.id
        #I get post_like from django-redis
        post_like = get_redis_connection("default")
        likes = post_like.get("post"+":"+str(post_id))
        if likes == None:
            return 0
        else:
            likes = likes.decode('utf-8')
            return likes
```

With the code above, I got what I need from the API.

Since 'likes' doesn't exist in my database(Mysql here), I can't using order_by('likes') to sort the data with django ORM

I follow the doc here [ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) which lead me to override list(): (I had override create() and get_queryset() before)

```
from operator import itemgetter

class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostAllSerializer


    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        #problem here
        serializer.data = sorted(serializer.data, key=itemgetter(serializer.data['likes']))
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        act_id = request.data.get('act')
        act = Act.objects.get(pk=act_id)
        if act.act_type == 0:
            if request.user != act.user:
                return Response(status=403)
        return super().create(request, args, kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-post_create_time')
        act_id = self.request.query_params.get('act_id', None)
        post_author = self.request.query_params.get('post_author', None)
        if act_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(act=act_id)
        if post_author is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user__user_name=post_author)
        return queryset
```

Nothing happened, What is wired is even when I uncomment

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Still nothing happened, Which part is wrong?

Another question is when I wanna add some extra data like 'question' when I use django FBV:

```
def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': 'some data I wanna add'})
```

Is it possible to add the data in serializer.data? For example, I wanna display user_id from which user request this api:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        user_id = request.user.id #how can I add the user_id into response data?
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I look around the docs here [Including extra context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context).

```
serializer = AccountSerializer(account, context={'request': request})
```

I don't really understand how to add data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Since 'likes' doesn't exist in my database(Mysql here), I can't using order_by('likes') to sort the data with django ORM"**

You wont be able to sort the results using django ORM as the likes field is not a part of your DB table. The only way to do it is to sort the serializer.data that you get in your view. In your case serializer.data will be a list of dictionary, you can use sort command for list and sort on likes using lambda.

One thing to take care here is as you will be doing the sort by loading the data in memory, make sure that you dont load a lot of data. Have a check on memory utilization.

**"Another question is when I wanna add some extra data like 'question' when I use django FBV"**

I did'nt understand what is needed here.

Comment: I tried override the list(), but nothing happened.I have updated my post for the second questions.

Comment: Thanks, I just miss 'if page is not None: ' this line